# Are intermediate variables necessary for a pandas boolean index? Syntax error comes up when I don't use one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning how to use pandas and trying to boolean index so that the dataframe is made up of rows where the value of the 'sector' column is 'Technology' and the 'country' column is not 'USA'. It works fine when I use an intermediate variable, like in the following:

```
t_nu = (f500['sector'] == 'Technology') & ~(f500['country'] == 'USA')
tech_outside_usa = f500[t_nu].head()
```

When I try to run without the intermediate variable, like this:

```
tech_outside_usa = f500[(f500['sector'] == 'Technology') & ~(f500['country'] == 'USA')].head()
```

I get an invalid syntax error. Can anyone tell me what the difference is?

Comment: what is the full traceback of the error? but i think this should work...`tech_outside_usa = f500[((f500['sector'] == 'Technology') & ~(f500['country'] == 'USA'))].head()`

Comment: I bet the real problem is something like a missing closing parenthesis on the previous line, that you had in one version of the code and not the other.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Chris, your version worked. I appreciate it. Do you happen to know if the extra set of parenthesis is needed because of the `& ~` operators?

Comment: @nicons it is required. Take a look at the pandas docs for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @Chris: Nothing in there says the extra parentheses you added are required. They're not required; the ones around the `&` operands are required due to precedence, but not the parentheses around the entire `&` expression.